# Rake Crashes since change to ZSH

Tags: ruby, macos, rake, rvm, zsh

I just recently started having this issue. I'm totally unaware as to what I have recently changed to get this behavior, but it's driving me crazy that it is now not working. I have provided as much details as I can as to my current system environment.

System Details
OS: Mavericks
Shell: ZSH (5.0.2) Oh My ZSH
Ruby: 2.0.0-p451
Rake: 10.1.1
Command-Line Tools: Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix

-- Crash report --

```
> Process:         ruby [63404] Path:           
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
> Identifier:      ruby Version:         96 Code Type:       X86-64
> (Native) Parent Process:  zsh [62217] Responsible:     iTerm [95439]
> User ID:         502
> 
> Date/Time:       2014-03-09 20:48:03.772 -0400 OS Version:      Mac OS
> X 10.9.2 (13C64) Report Version:  11 Anonymous UUID: 
> 5865E4EF-2686-B0AA-D22C-0089D3AA89C7
> 
> Sleep/Wake UUID: 2B1E7B16-10B4-42E9-9537-24305D033046
> 
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> 
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000418
> 
> VM Regions Near 0x418:
> --> 
>     __TEXT                 00000001056db000-00000001056dc000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW 
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
> 
> Application Specific Information: abort() called
> 
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0  
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8a31e866 __pthread_kill + 10
> 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8f9f535c pthread_kill +
> 92 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fff8bc48b1a abort + 125 3
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x000000010570fc2d rb_bug + 184 4  
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001057a4c02 0x1056e6000 + 781314
> 5   libsystem_platform.dylib          0x00007fff8c55b5aa _sigtramp + 26 6
> ???                               000000000000000000 0 + 0 7  
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x0000000105b76ac5 rb_newobj_of + 21
> (gc.c:687) 8   libruby.2.0.0.dylib            0x0000000105c22b3d
> str_new + 77 (string.c:376) 9   libruby.2.0.0.dylib          
>   0x0000000105b6883b rb_require + 11 (load.c:1026) 10  parser.bundle   
>   0x0000000105b24703 Init_parser + 19 (parser.rl:874) 11 
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001056e6d3a dln_load + 186 12 
> libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x00000001057f7379 rb_vm_call_cfunc +
> 416 13  libruby.2.0.0.dylib               0x0000000105717e56
> rb_require_safe + 1124 14  libruby.2.0.0.dylib          
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 15  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 16  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 17  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 18  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 19  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 20  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 21  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 22  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 23  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 24  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 25  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 26  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 27  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 28  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 29  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 30  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 31  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 32  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 33  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 34  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 35  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 36  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 37  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 38  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 39  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 40  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 41  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 42  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 43  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 44  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 45  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 46  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 47  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 48  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 49  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 50  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 51  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 52  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 53  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 54  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 55  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 56  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 57  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 58  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 59  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 60  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 61  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 62  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 63  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 64  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 65  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 66  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 67  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 68  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 69  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 70  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 71  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 72  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 73  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 74  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 75  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 76  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 77  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 78  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 79  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 80  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 81  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 82  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 83  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 84  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 85  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 86  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 87  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 88  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 89  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 90  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x0000000105717e1b rb_require_safe + 1065 91  libruby.2.0.0.dylib    
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 92  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 93  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 94  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 95  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 96  libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 97  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x000000010571854e 0x1056e6000 + 206158 98  libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 99  libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 100 libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 101 libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 102 libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6495 rb_iseq_eval + 366 103 libruby.2.0.0.dylib        
>   0x00000001057178c4 0x1056e6000 + 202948 104 libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x000000010571854e 0x1056e6000 + 206158 105 libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x00000001057fe195 0x1056e6000 + 1147285 106 libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057fdc58 0x1056e6000 + 1145944 107 libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057ecc3b 0x1056e6000 + 1076283 108 libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f6530 0x1056e6000 + 1115440 109 libruby.2.0.0.dylib     
>   0x00000001057f701a rb_iseq_eval_main + 138 110 libruby.2.0.0.dylib   
>   0x0000000105714888 0x1056e6000 + 190600 111 libruby.2.0.0.dylib      
>   0x00000001057147ca ruby_run_node + 47 112 ruby                       
>   0x00000001056dbf26 main + 79 113 libdyld.dylib                
>   0x00007fff852e45fd start + 1
> 
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a31f94a poll +
> 10 1   libruby.2.0.0.dylib            0x0000000105809411 0x1056e6000 +
> 1192977 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8f9f4899
> _pthread_body + 138 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8f9f472a _pthread_start + 137 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib  
>   0x00007fff8f9f8fc9 thread_start + 13
> 
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
> 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff766d2310  rcx: 0x00007fd69b8ea118 
> rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000507  rsi:
> 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fd69b8ea140  rsp: 0x00007fd69b8ea118  
> r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fd69b8e9f00  r10:
> 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206   r12: 0x0000000000000000 
> r13: 0x00007fd69b8de4a0  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15:
> 0x0000000105d0d4c0   rip: 0x00007fff8a31e866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206 
> cr2: 0x00007fd69b8e9f38    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:     
> 0x02000148 Trap Number:     133
> 
> 
> Binary Images:
>        0x1056db000 -        0x1056dbfff  ruby (96) <123C862F-51DB-3DA1-81C0-D9C7444D4FC6>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
>        0x1056e6000 -        0x105879fff  libruby.2.0.0.dylib (96) <EF561B91-2588-3589-9214-5EB00B4A45CD>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>        0x1059f6000 -        0x1059f7fff  encdb.bundle (96) <0B236232-4887-38A6-8B84-6E53A7260368>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/enc/encdb.bundle
>        0x1059fc000 -        0x1059fdfff  transdb.bundle (96) <B6DDE883-93B7-30C7-B856-7E498168F6CE>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
>        0x105a23000 -        0x105a24fff  etc.bundle (96) <499CE9CA-C088-3BD0-A8D4-6851D863F3CE>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/etc.bundle
>        0x105a29000 -        0x105a2cfff  pathname.bundle (96) <9CD09C63-0E2B-3E32-8945-C78F984A97DA>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/pathname.bundle
>        0x105a32000 -        0x105a32fff  sha1.bundle (96) <623AC56D-F4BC-3363-91B8-C53F847017C6>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/digest/sha1.bundle
>        0x105a37000 -        0x105a38fff  digest.bundle (96) <552ED206-66E7-3E63-9B11-6547E5D66822>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/digest.bundle
>        0x105a3e000 -        0x105a57fff  socket.bundle (96) <504083E0-B94F-3D28-88C7-433FE3091E83>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/socket.bundle
>        0x105a60000 -        0x105a60fff  fcntl.bundle (96) <9DBA58DA-38CA-3EEB-8F97-FD13FD4315F2>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/fcntl.bundle
>        0x105a65000 -        0x105a94fff  openssl.bundle (96) <5CB96EBE-BEB3-3B13-9056-57A22D111636>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/openssl.bundle
>        0x105aab000 -        0x105aaefff  stringio.bundle (96) <9F8E5F9F-E1F9-3F47-AC0A-C0516CA5E856>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/stringio.bundle
>        0x105ab4000 -        0x105ab6fff  strscan.bundle (96) <2A08CF1D-8433-3F8B-9E17-E2D5E821C5CB>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/strscan.bundle
>        0x105abc000 -        0x105ac7fff  bigdecimal.bundle (96) <860FFFB0-DF1F-3A97-BB77-A8AA5D235155>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/bigdecimal.bundle
>        0x105acd000 -        0x105af8fff  date_core.bundle (96) <40291422-B406-3BA3-AF51-A4F58292E1D3>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/date_core.bundle
>        0x105b01000 -        0x105b1dfff  psych.bundle (96) <2291A89F-1525-33D1-BC6E-32CB2881D59E>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/psych.bundle
>        0x105b24000 -        0x105b27ff7 +parser.bundle (0) <D682DAAF-E202-35F2-A678-0D6733FD708F> /Users/USER/*/parser.bundle
>        0x105b2c000 -        0x105d07ff7 +libruby.2.0.0.dylib (0) <B033A56C-FB48-373B-8575-E02AD4AA274F>
> /Users/USER/*/libruby.2.0.0.dylib
>     0x7fff6635d000 -     0x7fff66390817  dyld (239.4) <2B17750C-ED1B-3060-B64E-21897D08B28B> /usr/lib/dyld
>     0x7fff8485e000 -     0x7fff848acfff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7>
> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
>     0x7fff852e1000 -     0x7fff852e4ff7  libdyld.dylib (239.4) <CF03004F-58E4-3BB6-B3FD-BE4E05F128A0> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
>     0x7fff852ef000 -     0x7fff852f3ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <BDC1E65B-72A1-3DA3-A57C-B23159CAAD0B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
>     0x7fff85477000 -     0x7fff85478ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100)
> <4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E>
> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
>     0x7fff85688000 -     0x7fff85689ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.11) <5E5A6E09-33A9-391A-AB34-E57D93BB1551>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
>     0x7fff85e64000 -     0x7fff85e8bffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <7D41A156-D285-3849-A2C3-C04ADE797D98>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
>     0x7fff86c2e000 -     0x7fff86c37ff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (121) <52571EC3-6894-37E4-946E-064B021ED44E>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
>     0x7fff87856000 -     0x7fff8787dff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
>     0x7fff87f40000 -     0x7fff880edf27  libobjc.A.dylib (551.1) <AD7FD984-271E-30F4-A361-6B20319EC73B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x7fff8891a000 -     0x7fff88943ff7  libc++abi.dylib (49.1) <21A807D3-6732-3455-B77F-743E9F916DF0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
>     0x7fff894c7000 -     0x7fff894c8fff  libunc.dylib (28) <62682455-1862-36FE-8A04-7A6B91256438> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
>     0x7fff896a3000 -     0x7fff896a4fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25)
> <334A82F4-4AE4-3719-A511-86D0B0723E2B>
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
>     0x7fff8a309000 -     0x7fff8a325ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.90.20) <20E00C54-9222-359F-BD98-CB79ABED769A>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x7fff8a326000 -     0x7fff8a355fd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <B7F0E2E4-2777-33FC-A787-D6430B630D54>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
>     0x7fff8b5c8000 -     0x7fff8b60aff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
>     0x7fff8bbde000 -     0x7fff8bbe0ff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <7A1A2BCB-C03D-3A25-BFA4-3E569B2D2C38>
> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
>     0x7fff8bbec000 -     0x7fff8bc75ff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.90.3) <6FD3A400-4BB2-3B95-B90C-BE6E9D0D78FA>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x7fff8bf23000 -     0x7fff8bf27ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.90.3) <1A55AF8A-B6C4-3163-B557-3AD25DA643A8>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
>     0x7fff8bf4c000 -     0x7fff8bf54fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.90.2) <A0B7CF19-D9F2-33D4-8107-A62184C9066E>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
>     0x7fff8c15c000 -     0x7fff8c15dff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <FB856CD1-2AEA-3907-8E9B-1E54B6827F82>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
>     0x7fff8c558000 -     0x7fff8c55eff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.90.1) <3C3D3DA8-32B9-3243-98EC-D89B9A1670B3>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
>     0x7fff8c641000 -     0x7fff8c64bfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D>
> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
>     0x7fff8c6d2000 -     0x7fff8c6d7fff  libmacho.dylib (845) <1D2910DF-C036-3A82-A3FD-44FF73B5FF9B> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
>     0x7fff8d9cd000 -     0x7fff8d9d4ff3  libcopyfile.dylib (103) <5A881779-D0D6-3029-B371-E3021C2DDA5E>
> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
>     0x7fff8ddde000 -     0x7fff8dddfff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <BFC0DC97-46C6-3BE0-9983-54A98734897A> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x7fff8e14c000 -     0x7fff8e166fff  libdispatch.dylib (339.90.1) <F3CBFE1B-FCE8-3F33-A53D-9092AB382DBB>
> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
>     0x7fff8e3b6000 -     0x7fff8e3b6ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <3AA8D85D-CF00-3BD3-A5A0-E28E1A32A6D8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
>     0x7fff8e3b7000 -     0x7fff8e3b9ff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.13) <B51C8C22-C455-36AC-952D-A319B6545884>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
>     0x7fff8e892000 -     0x7fff8e8a3ff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
>     0x7fff8ee8d000 -     0x7fff8ee94ff8  liblaunch.dylib (842.90.1) <38D1AB2C-A476-385F-8EA8-7AB604CA1F89> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
>     0x7fff8f9f3000 -     0x7fff8f9faff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.4) <AB498556-B555-310E-9041-F67EC9E00E2C>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x7fff905df000 -     0x7fff90603fff  libxpc.dylib (300.90.2) <AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
>     0x7fff90927000 -     0x7fff90a06fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (50) <B95B9DBA-39D3-3EEF-AF43-44608B28894E> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
>     0x7fff90b37000 -     0x7fff90b3efff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <4CD916B2-1B17-362A-B403-EF24A1DAC141>
> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
>     0x7fff91517000 -     0x7fff91569fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
>     0x7fff91855000 -     0x7fff9185aff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <78DCC358-2FC1-302E-B395-0155B47CB547> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
>     0x7fff91db5000 -     0x7fff91db6ffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF>
> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
>     0x7fff91de1000 -     0x7fff91e15fff  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (50) <B15F967C-B002-36C2-9621-3456D8509F50> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
>     0x7fff91e53000 -     0x7fff91e6eff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.10.1) <A695B4E4-38E9-332E-A772-29D31E3F1385>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
>     0x7fff92520000 -     0x7fff92531ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <655FB343-52CF-3E2F-B14D-BEBF5AAEF94D>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
> 
> External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
> targeting this process:
>     task_for_pid: 0
>     thread_create: 0
>     thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
>     task_for_pid: 0
>     thread_create: 0
>     thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
>     task_for_pid: 64857
>     thread_create: 7
>     thread_set_state: 0
> 
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=76.9M
> resident=23.7M(31%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=53.2M(69%) Writable
> regions: Total=58.0M written=12.6M(22%) resident=23.2M(40%)
> swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=34.8M(60%)   REGION TYPE               
> VIRTUAL
> ===========                      ======= Kernel Alloc Once                     4K MALLOC                             49.3M MALLOC (admin)            
> 16K STACK GUARD                           4K Stack                    
> 64.0M VM_ALLOCATE                          12K
> __DATA                             1160K
> __LINKEDIT                         66.6M
> __TEXT                             10.3M shared memory                         4K
> ===========                      ======= TOTAL                             191.4M
```

Comment: Yes I did...somehow my rake version want the same as the Ruby version I was in. When I ran using bundle exec that's what told me something was wrong